# How to Handle Multidimensional Array in Ajax through PHP(code igniter) and Jason

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, geojson

Here is the Html where i want to display data from database using ajax

```
<div id="specContWrap">
  <div id="overViewWrap" class="overViewTableCon">
    <div class="overViewTable on">
      <div class="tit">Overview</div>
      <table class="infoTableType">
        <caption>Overview Table</caption>
        <tbody id="overview_details">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Category</th>
            <td> Commercial</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Product label</th>
            <td> Select Trim </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Model name</th>
            <td> H-1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Seats</th>
            <td>Select Trim</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- //.overViewTable -->
  </div>
  <!-- toggle : s -->
  <div class="togListWrap small  sepcListWrap" id="overviewh1">
    <div class="togList">
      <button class="btnOpenClose ">Performance</button>
      <div class="togCont " id="performanceWrap">
        Select Trim
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="togList">
      <button class="btnOpenClose ">Dimension</button>
      <div class="togCont " id="dimensionWrap">
        <div class="dimension on">
          Select Trim
        </div>
        <!-- //demention -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="togList">
      <button class="btnOpenClose ">Wheels</button>
      <div class="togCont " id="wheelsWrap">
        <div class="wheels on">
          Select Trim
        </div>
        <!-- //wheels -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="htmSpecContWrap" class="hide">
</div
```

Here is the j Query on change  Function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selTrim').change(function() {
    var trim_id1 = $(this).val();
    if (trim_id1) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?= base_url();?>H1_specifications/h1_trim_detail',
        data: 'trim_id1=' + trim_id1,
        datatype: 'Jason',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          // here i want to Display data up in the html,
          //which had responded through controller.
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here The controller function

```
public function h1_trim_detail(){
    $id = $_POST['trim_id1'];
    if(isset($_POST['trim_id1']) !== NULL){
        $this->load->model('Admin_panel');

        $results['overview_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_details_specification($id);
        $results['cargo_details'] = $this->Admin_panel->select_h1_Cargo($id);
        $results['engine_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_engine($id);
        $results['exterior_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_exterior($id);
        $results['feul_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_feul_comsuption($id);
        $results['weight_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_weight($id);
        $results['wheels_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_wheels($id);
        $results['transmission_details'] =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_transmission($id);

        exit(json_encode($results));

    }
}
```

I want to get all tables data and show it on view through ajax, jason but i have not idea about that how to handle multidimensional array(php) encoded into  jason ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here The controller function

```
public function h1_trim_detail(){
        $id = $_POST['trim_id1'];
        if(isset($_POST['trim_id1']) !== NULL){
            $this->load->model('Admin_panel');

            $rows7 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_details_specification($id);
            $rows = $this->Admin_panel->select_h1_Cargo($id);
            $rows1 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_engine($id);
            $rows2 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_exterior($id);
            $rows3 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_feul_comsuption($id);
            $rows4 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_weight($id);
            $rows5 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_wheels($id);
            $rows6 =$this->Admin_panel->select_h1_transmission($id);

            echo "<div id='specContWrap'>";
                if($rows7 !== false){
                    echo "<div id='overViewWrap' class='overViewTableCon'>";
                    echo "<div class='overViewTable on'>";
                        echo "<div class='tit'>Overview</div>";
                        echo "<table class='infoTableType'>";
                            echo "<caption>Overview Table</caption>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th scope='row'>Category</th>";
                                        echo "<td>Commercial</td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                foreach($rows7 as $row){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th scope='row'>Product label</th>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th scope='row'>Model name</th>";
                                    echo "<td>". $row['name_car']."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th scope='row'>Seats</th>";
                                    echo "<td>". $row['seats']."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }

                                echo "</tbody>";
                            echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                }else{
                    echo "Not Found";
                }


                echo "<div class='togListWrap small  sepcListWrap' id='overviewh1'>";
                    echo "<div class='togList'>";
                        echo "<button class='btnOpenClose'>Performance</button>";
                        echo "<div class='togCont' id='performanceWrap'>";

                        echo "<div class='performance on'>";
                            if($rows1 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Engine Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows1 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['descriptions']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }
                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Engine Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }
                            if($rows3 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Feul Comsuption Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows3 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['description']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }

                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Feul Comsuption Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }
                            if($rows6 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Transmission Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows6 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['descriptions']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }

                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Transmission Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div class='togList'>";
                        echo "<button class='btnOpenClose'>Dimension</button>";
                        echo "<div class='togCont' id='DimensionWrap'>";

                        echo "<div class='Dimension on'>";
                            if($rows2 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Exterior Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows2 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['description']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }
                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Exterior Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }
                            if($rows4 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Weight Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows4 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['description']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd><br>";
                                }

                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Weight Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }

                            if($rows !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Cargo Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['description']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }
                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Cargo Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div class='togList'>";
                        echo "<button class='btnOpenClose'>Wheels</button>";
                        echo "<div class='togCont' id='WheelsWrap'>";

                        echo "<div class='Wheels on'>";
                            if($rows5 !== false){
                                echo "<dl class='specList'>";
                                echo "<dt>Wheels Specification</dt>";
                                foreach($rows5 as $row){
                                echo "<dd>";
                                    echo "<dl>";
                                        echo "<dt>".$row['label']."</dt>";
                                        echo "<dd>".$row['description']."</dd>";
                                    echo "</dl>";
                                echo "</dd>";
                                }
                                echo "</dl><br>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<dt>Wheels Specification Not Found</dt><br>";
                            }

                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

Here is the j Query on change Function

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selTrim').change(function(){
            var trim_id1 = $(this).val();
            if(trim_id1){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?= base_url();?>H1_specifications/h1_trim_detail',
                    data:'trim_id1='+trim_id1,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#specContWrap').html(data);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the Html where i want to display data from database using ajax

```
<div class="specsContent" id="spec" data-modelyear="T9-2015">
            <!-- specsContent : s -->
            <div class="subTit2">Specification</div>
            <div class="sortSelect">
                <div class="tit">Choose a Trim</div>
                <select title="Choose a Trim" id="selTrim" name="selTrim" class="bgLB">
                    <option disabled selected>Choose your Trim</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($result as $row){
                        echo "<option value=".$row['trim_id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="specContWrap">
                <div id="overViewWrap" class="overViewTableCon">
                    <div class="overViewTable on">
                        <div class="tit">Overview</div>
                        <table class="infoTableType">
                            <caption>Overview Table</caption>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Category</th>
                                    <td> Commercial</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Product label</th>
                                    <td> Select Trim </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Model name</th>
                                    <td> H-1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Seats</th>
                                    <td>Select Trim</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div><!-- //.overViewTable -->
                </div>
                <!-- toggle : s -->
                <div class="togListWrap small  sepcListWrap" id="overviewh1">
                    <div class="togList">
                        <button class="btnOpenClose ">Performance</button>
                        <div class="togCont " id="performanceWrap">
                        Select Trim
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="togList">
                        <button class="btnOpenClose ">Dimension</button>
                        <div class="togCont " id="dimensionWrap">
                            <div class="dimension on">
                            Select Trim
                            </div><!-- //demention -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="togList">
                        <button class="btnOpenClose ">Wheels</button>
                        <div class="togCont " id="wheelsWrap">
                            <div class="wheels on">
                            Select Trim
                            </div><!-- //wheels -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="htmSpecContWrap" class="hide"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selTrim').change(function(){
            var trim_id1 = $(this).val();
            if(trim_id1){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?= base_url();?>H1_specifications/h1_trim_detail',
                    data:'trim_id1='+trim_id1,
                    datatype:'Json',
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response.success==1){
                            $('#PlaceWhereYouWantToPlace').html(response.data);
                        }else{
                            $('#').text('No Data Found');
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

I always prepare my HTML code in the controller and simply place in view. The reason of preparing ajax HTML data in the controller is I can easily change and manipulate the data and HTML content.

```
foreach($propertyAddedData as $propertyAddedData){
$table_data .= '<tr>
                <td><a href='.base_url('property/property_details/'.base64_encode($propertyAddedData['data']['id'])).'>'.$propertyAddedData['data']['property_address'].'</a></td>
                <td>$'.$propertyAddedData['data']['price'].'</td>
                <td>'.$propertyAddedData['data']['bedrooms'].'</td>
                <td>'.$propertyAddedData['data']['bathrooms'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $error = 0; 
}else{
    $error = 1; 
}

$propertyData = '<div class="mt-property-desc">
                 <table class="table-fixed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Beds</th>
                            <th>Baths</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><span class="gap-50"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        '.$table_data.'
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>';
$data    = $propertyData;
echo json_encode(array('error'=>$error,'data'=>$data));
exit;
```

**I hope it will make you clear but if didn't please let me know i will explain you**

Comment: Thank you Buddy Yes I have done this method, But their is the problem with this , That code is not working on those Browsers which Have VPN install in them

Comment: request not responding even just for echo "Done";

Comment: Can you post your  full controlller and ajax and html code

Comment: it's up their i am posting previous code without jason

Comment: Please Check Below Code

Comment: Don't make this way, Make a json request and get response as json just the way i did in my project ,please try it will definitely work

Comment: Can i replace echo  with  $html .=

Comment: i had make it group but showing /t /n and not getting css

Comment: can you please help me at one another thing when i encode it , it is adding \ in to closing tags like this  <\/table>

Comment: Share me your lastest code controller code and ajax and html

Comment: Thank You buddy Solved my problem

Comment: i have just add JSON.parse()

Comment: But buddy still have that VPN problem

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
success: function(data) {
     console.log( data.overview_detail);
     console.log( data.cargo_details);
     ... and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks For reply Buddy but its is Showing "Undefined" in console

Comment: @FahadNadeem echo json_encode($result); instead of exit;

Answer (score 0):

// use json_encode() from php end and To decode in javascript use below code

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Thank You Bro then how to Show up in the Html here is the parsed array               
            "                  
  {overview_details: Array(1)}overview_details: Array(1)0: cat_id: "4"description: "The "Dynamic Precision" advanced with Hyundai's Fluidic Sculpture 2.0 philosophy captures the modernity of the sporty, avant-garde design of the brand-new H-1."name: "BusA2e"name_car: "H-1"seats: "4"trim_id: "3"vehicle_id: "7"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
temp1"

Comment: from php end decode this json data using json_decode() function. you will get your data in array format again.